# Any controls like Devexpress ASPX PivotTable/Gride available for Java webapp?

Tags: java, asp.net, devexpress, pivot

I've just been looking around a little at the Devexpress PivotGrid/PivotTable and wow, I'm impressed (see [here](http://tv.devexpress.com/#ASPxPivotGrid101intro) for an example, skip towards end to see some of the functionality).

I'm working on a java webapp in which the tabular data presented is the key part of the application, and if I could implement something such as the Devexpress control that would be amazing. Is there anything out there?? The java webapp uses the myfaces framework.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

for olap - Mondrian (pentaho)

components primefaces, icefaces and adf of oracle.

all for jsf.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your kind words about our Pivot Grid control – have you submitted a request to us via our Support Center... 
http://Devexpress.com/support

Comment: A request with regards to what? Are you suggesting that there would be some way to run a devexpress control in a java webapp?? This isn't just an attempt at getting links pointing back to the devexpress website by any chance??

Comment: A request with regards to supporting more platforms. Our Pivot control is available for ASP.NET and WinForms. We're targeting more in the future. I recommend adding that suggestion to our support center so if we get a lot of requests then we'll considering bringing to market a version for other platforms.